# Cannot Figure Out Why Array Writing Isn't Working

Tags: java, arrays

For the last hour and a half now, I have been working on some code for my class and I can NOT figure out why one piece of it is not working. Every time I run it, it says `java.util.InputMismatchException`.

`double array[][] = createArray(inputFileName);` is the call to the `createArray()` method which I am having problems with.

The information the array uses is in a .txt file. The first 2 numbers are both int and they determine the rows and the columns in my array. All the numbers after that are doubles that go INTO the array. I have managed to get it to read the ints (not that it's a challenge), but for some reason I can NOT figure out how or why it doesn't want to work with the rest of it.

At this point it's more than likely something small I am looking over because of my frustration, but I would very much appreciate if someone could explain what the problem is so that I don't have to deal with it every single time I need to create an array.

If more information is needed, please let me know. Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String chooseMessage = "welcome";
        String userName = "";
        String inputFileName = "";
        String outputFileName = "";
        double arrayAverage;
        double arrayMin;
        double arrayMax;



        chooseMessage = displayMessage(chooseMessage, inputFileName, outputFileName);
        chooseMessage = displayMessage(chooseMessage, inputFileName, outputFileName);
        userName = getName();
        inputFileName = getInputFileName();
        outputFileName = getOutputFileName();
        double array[][] = createArray(inputFileName);
        arrayAverage = computeAverage(array);
        arrayMin = findMin(array);
        arrayMax = findMax(array);
        printOut(inputFileName, outputFileName, arrayAverage, arrayMin, arrayMax);
        chooseMessage = displayMessage(chooseMessage, inputFileName, outputFileName);
        chooseMessage = displayMessage(chooseMessage, inputFileName, outputFileName);


    }


    public static double[][] createArray(String inputFileName) throws FileNotFoundException { //reads the input file and creates an array

        File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
        Scanner FileReader = new Scanner(inputFile);

        int rows = FileReader.nextInt();
        int columns = FileReader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("rows: " + rows);
        double[][] newArray = new double[rows][columns];

        for (int i=0; i<(newArray.length); i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<newArray[i].length; j++)
                newArray[i][j] = FileReader.nextInt();
        }

        FileReader.close();
        //System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(newArray));
        return newArray;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing handling of double values.  Are you using nextDouble() instead of nextInt()?  newArray[i][j] = FileReader.nextDouble();, perhaps?

Comment: Could you share an example of the input file please?

Comment: Here is an input file example:

3
5
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
10.0
-1.0
-2.0
-3.0
-4.0
-5.0

Comment: It ought to call next double(). Debugging tips: Read the stack traceback and notice which line of your code caused the exception. Also you can step through the code in the debugger. That's an extremely helpful tool.

Comment: Since I deleted my previous comment:

When I enter nextDouble() instead of nextInt(), I get a "java.util.NoSuchElementException" instead.

I'm sorry if this is all so "petty", I'm very new to this.

Comment: And NOW using nextDouble() seems to have worked, even though I just tried it before now and it gave me a different error.

Comment: Thank you for catching that mistake.
The first time I changed it from nextInt() to nextDouble(), it didn't work for some reason. I figured I would try once more and now it does.
I can't believe I spent that long for just one little word.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem..

```
for (int i=0; i<(newArray.length); i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<newArray[i].length; j++)
                newArray[i][j] = FileReader.nextInt();  // This might be the problem... 
        }
```

You should be using

```
FilReader.nextDouble()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be.

```
double[][] array  = createArray(inputFileName);
```

Comment: This is just a different way to initialize "array", and since Java excepts both forms, this does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

[java.util.InputMismatchException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html)

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

In your case for first two inputs,it works fine.But after that your file contains double values and you are trying to read it using `nextInt` so this `InputMismatchException` is thrown.

**Solution**

Instead of this

```
 newArray[i][j] = FileReader.nextInt();
```

use

```
newArray[i][j] = FileReader.nextDouble();
```